# What is the canonical approach to use for autoconf dependencies in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, shared-libraries, autoconf

I have a command line tool project that is today built with autoconf. This command line tool project in turn has dependencies on shared libraries, also built with autoconf.

I want to build this command line tool using Xcode.

The starting point I understand is creating a MacOS Command Line Project in Xcode.

What is the canonical way of handling the dependencies on autoconf built shared libraries within that Xcode Command Line Project?

Should I be building the autoconf built shared libraries as MacOS Framework Projects, and depending on these?

Is there a repository of Xcode Frameworks somewhere I should be aware of, or is it expected that I create framework projects from scratch?

To be clear: I am asking for the canonical Apple recommended way to do this, where someone can check out a project, open up Xcode and get going. I am not looking for any hack methods that would require specialist knowledge or multiple steps.